# much more relate/more relate

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, grammaticality, comparison

Can I use the following sentence constructions:

- I **much more** relate to A than to B

or should I say

- I **more** relate to A than to B

?

Comment: I prefer 'more' after 'relate'. I relate more to Jones than to Smith. Preverbal 'more' sounds conversational to me, and preverbal 'much more' sounds even more colloquial. Opinions may vary.

Answer (score 1):

"More" doesn't go well with "relate" for me.

You relate well or badly, not more or less, and the adverb should follow the verb

> I relate much better to A than to B

> I relate to A much better than B

Comment: I disagree, if OP is using relate in the sense of relating to a feeling or idea, rather than a person.

Answer (score 0):

I relate more to A than B. You can relate more or less to different things.It's easier to understand written this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you put "more" **after** "relate," your examples are fine:

> I relate much more to A than to B.
>
> I relate more to A than to B.